# ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /var/www/html/idi/client2/node_modules/@ng-idle/keepalive/index.d.ts

Tags: angular, angular5

i have added `ng-idle/keepalive`.

this is my `package.json` file

```
{
    "name": "azimuth",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "install": "napa"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "4.3.3",
        "@angular/common": "4.3.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.3.1",
        "@angular/core": "4.3.1",
        "@angular/forms": "4.3.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.1",
        "@angular/router": "4.3.1",
        "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.13",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.13",
        "angular2-datatable": "0.6.0",
        "angular2-froala-wysiwyg": "2.5.1-2",
        "angular2-google-maps": "0.17.0",
        "angular2-google-place": "^2.0.2",
        "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
        "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.3",
        "awesome-bootstrap-checkbox": "1.0.0-alpha.4",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
        "chart.js": "2.5.0",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "d3": "3.5.17",
        "datamaps": "0.5.8",
        "dropzone": "4.3.0",
        "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
        "fullcalendar": "3.2.0",
        "jquery": "3.1.1",
        "jquery-knob": "1.2.11",
        "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
        "jquery-ui-dist": "1.12.1",
        "jqwidgets-framework": "^4.6.4",
        "leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
        "mdn-polyfills": "^5.4.0",
        "metrojs": "0.9.77",
        "moment": "2.17.1",
        "ng2-charts": "1.5.0",
        "ngx-toastr": "^5.3.1",
        "primeng": "^4.0.0-rc.3",
        "rxjs": "5.2.0",
        "skycons": "^1.0.0",
        "socicon": "3.0.4",
        "tether": "1.4.0",
        "text-mask-addons": "^3.6.0",
        "topojson": "2.2.0",
        "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
        "widgster": "0.0.3",
        "zone.js": "0.8.5"
    },
    "napa": {
        "pace": "https://github.com/HubSpot/pace.git#v0.7.1",
        "skycons": "https://github.com/darkskyapp/skycons.git#7095ecf5f653dbcadbddb0d317b42e65fe091eae"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.2.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.1",
        "@types/core-js": "0.9.41",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
        "@types/jquery": "2.0.41",
        "@types/jquery.slimscroll": "1.3.30",
        "@types/node": "7.0.12",
        "codelyzer": "2.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
        "karma": "1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
        "napa": "2.3.0",
        "protractor": "5.1.1",
        "sass-to-js": "1.3.0",
        "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
        "ts-node": "3.0.2",
        "tslint": "5.0.0",
        "typescript": "2.2.
    }
}
```

and this is my `app.component.ts` file

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { AppConfig } from "./app.config";
import { Idle, DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES } from '@ng-idle/core';
import { Keepalive } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/pairwise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'az-root',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [AppConfig]
})

export class AppComponent {
  router: any;
  showNavbar: any;
  loginToken: any = '';
  currentUrl: any;
  timedOut = false;
  userInactivityTimeOut: any;
  ticks = 10;
  downloadTimer: any = '';
  timeleft: any;

  constructor(router: Router, public route: Router, public http: Http, public config: AppConfig, private idle: Idle, private keepalive: Keepalive) {
    this.router = router;
    this.currentUrl = window.location.href;
    this.currentUrl = this.currentUrl.split('/');
    this.loginToken = config.loginToken;
    this.router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .pairwise().subscribe((e) => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
          if (e && e[0] && e[0].url && e[1] && e[1].url && e[1].url === '/') {
            this.route.navigate([e[0].url]);
          }
        }
      });

    if (this.currentUrl) {
      if ((this.currentUrl.indexOf('changerecoverpassword') > -1) || (this.currentUrl.indexOf('forgotpassword') > -1) || (this.currentUrl.indexOf('verifycode') > -1) || (this.currentUrl.indexOf('verifysms') > -1)) {
        return;
      } else {
        if ((this.loginToken === '') || (this.loginToken === null)) {
          this.route.navigate(['/']);
        }
      }
    }
    if (this.route.url === '/') {
      this.showNavbar = false;
    } else {
      this.showNavbar = true;
    }

    this.userInactivityTimeOut = config.userInactivityTimeOut;

    // sets an idle timeout of 5 seconds, for testing purposes.
    idle.setIdle(this.userInactivityTimeOut);
    // sets a timeout period of 5 seconds. after 10 seconds of inactivity, the user will be considered timed out.
    idle.setTimeout(this.userInactivityTimeOut);
    // sets the default interrupts, in this case, things like clicks, scrolls, touches to the document
    idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

    idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.route && this.route.url) {
        if ((this.route.url === '/') || (this.route.url === '/changerecoverpassword') || (this.route.url === '/forgotpassword') || (this.route.url === '/verifycode') || (this.route.url === '/verifysms')) {
          this.reset();
          return;
        } else {
          this.timeleft = 10;
          this.downloadTimer = setInterval(() => {
            $('#progressBar').value = 10 - --this.timeleft;
            this.ticks = this.timeleft;
            if (this.timeleft <= 0) {
              this.logout();
              clearInterval(this.downloadTimer);
            }
          }, 1000);
          setTimeout(() => {
            $('#timeOutModal').modal('show');
          }, 200);
          this.timedOut = true;
        }
      }
    });

    keepalive.interval(this.userInactivityTimeOut);

    this.reset();

  }

  // reset timer for user inactivity
  reset() {
    this.idle.watch();
    this.timedOut = false;
    if (this.ticks && this.ticks >= 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(this.downloadTimer);
        $('#timeOutModal').modal('hide');
        this.ticks = 10;
      }, 200);
    }
  }

  // logout and redirect to login page
  logout() {
    this.reset();
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#timeOutModal').modal('hide');
      this.config.clearLocalStorage();
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }, 200);
  }

}
```

I have added `ng-idle` and `ng-idle/keepalive` package latest.

its getting after running `ng serve` can any one please help to solve this error.

i'am getting this error

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /var/www/html/idi/client2/node_modules/@ng-idle/keepalive/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/html/idi/client2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/html/idi/client2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/html/idi/client2/src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the author built the module with Angular5+ by looking at the metadata file:

```
node_modules\@ng-idle\core\index.metadata.json
```

The contents show version 4 of the metadata, which Angular 5 introduced:

```
[{"__symbolic":"module","version":4,"metadata":...
```

Angular4 is on metadata version 3.

You need an earlier version of this library. i.e. look for a release on npm which uses version 3.

**[Update]**

I just checked.  You should install @2.0.0-beta.12:

```
npm install @ng-idle/core@2.0.0-beta.12
npm install @ng-idle/keepalive@2.0.0-beta.12
```

Comment: i have run this npm install @ng-idle/core@2.0.0-beta.12 command but still error is not fixed. still getting   ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /var/www/html/idi/client2/node_modules/@ng-idle/keepalive/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/html/idi/client2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/html/idi/client2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/html/idi/client2/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: you need to also rollback @ng-idle/keepalive - same issue.

Comment: if i upgrade to angular5 is there any chance to fix this error or i also run npm install @ng-idle/keepalive@2.0.0-beta.12

Comment: yes, upgrading to ng5 should work.  However there were breaking changes from ng4 to ng5 - it might require some re-work.

Comment: ng serve and ng build running successfully but in console im getting this error 

AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
 can u please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of the library you're using, see https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng2-idle/issues/76.

Furthermore, you should never, ever use apache to host a dev environment of your app, use `ng build -prod` to produce a build and copy `dist` folder content into your apache directory.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm just downgrade to beta12 both

```
   "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
   "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.12"
```

, its working for me.
My dev environment solution is in Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in order to make it work I had to add

`"@ng-idle/core": "2.0.0-beta.12",`
`"@ng-idle/keepalive": "2.0.0-beta.12"`

in my package.json, then I ran

`npm install`

Note that the version is fixed to 2.0.0-beta.12 as the `^` *(caret)* is not present in front of the version number.

Thanks [@chrisDev-ec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5572912/chrisdev-ec) and [@pixelbits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3661630/pixelbits) for guiding me into finding the solution

The build now goes through without any error. I don't want to update just yet to ng5, so I find this solution pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.12" which will pull the latest version 
 at the moment 13, please make sure you have "@ng-idle/core": "2.0.0-beta.12" (without the caret) which will force it to pull down version 12.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that hasn't already been said in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Running this command solved the issue for me:

npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 --save